# Entity whose possible types differ in the FK

Tags: database-design, erd

I have one entity called "Groups".

"Groups" can be of different types and the difference between each type is the FK.

For instance, if a "Group" is of type "Event Group", then it uses eventID; if it's of type "Institution Group", then it uses institutionID.

What's the proper way to model this?

Comment: See this Q/A from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896831/how-to-implement-referential-integrity-in-subtypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventGroup would be one table, InstitutionGroup would be another, each with their own primary key and correlating fields. The foreign key in Group on eventID would reference the primary key in EventGroup, and the foreign key institutionID would reference the primary key in InstitutionGroup.